# Django Unicode Error While Rendering Image through template

Tags: django, python-2.7, matplotlib, django-templates, django-views

I am rendering an Image in django(1.9) Python 2.7.10. It works Fine.

> views.py

```
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
response = django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
plt.close(fig)
return response
```

The code above always publishes the Image in browser from the beginning of line. I want to position the Image to a new location in browser. I tried passing the response variable in a template.

> views.py

```
canvas = FigureCanvas(fig)
response = django.http.HttpResponse(content_type='image/png')
canvas.print_png(response)
plt.close(fig)
context = {'response': response}
return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

> index.html

```
<div align="center" style="text-align:center;">{{ response }} </div>
```

The problem here is i get the error:

> 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 27: invalid start byte. You passed in HttpResponse status_code=200, "image/png" (class 'django.http.response.HttpResponse')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set up your own url for your view (note this can be the view that you had listed that works), Add in urls.py:

```
  url('^show_graph/$', yourview, name="show_graph"),
```

Then you can show this image in your html by putting into index.html:

```
<img src={% url "show_graph" %} height="400" width="400">
```

Comment: <img src={% url "show_graph" %} height="400" width="400"> is giving me error "tag start is not closed" 
what is url here is it a variable?

Comment: url is the django templatetag: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/#url - for the error - please check the punctuation and wihte spaces in your template. The code should works as Iisted.

Comment: Thanks for help but Image is still not showing...a blank page

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>

<img src={% url "show_graph" %} height="400" width="400">

</body>
</html>

I am using Pycharm...It says url attribute url is not allowed here
what am I missing

Comment: you can also hardcode the path to the view (although this is not recommended). <img src="/show_graph" height="400" width="400">. The path should be the url to the view that works.